# When new cell inserted, current viewing cell goes down. Is there any way to handle that?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview getting data from server. So each time new cell will be added to top of the tableview when new data received. So when I'm in 10th cell it will go down and my visible cell changed to 9th cell when new data received. I know its the behaviour of tableview, But for user it may not be a good experience. So is there any way to handle that situation? ie If new cell added on the top, current cell(lets say its 10th cell i am viewing) must be there without going down.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. Compare indexPath from this method with index paths from `[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]`. If indexPath is not the last index path from this array, scroll your table to the second index path from `indexPathsForVisibleRows` using `[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]` with scroll position top.

p.s.: i did not try this, maybe you need to think about better conditions to make it work like you want.